# Creating RESTful Webservice in CQ5,AEM

Tags: rest, aem, sling

I want to host restful webservice from CQ5. Basically the intention is to expose all the users present in CQ5 to external systems based on some parameters like modified date, user state etc.
I went through https://chanchal.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/using-jax-rs-and-jersey-to-write-restful-services-in-osgi-apache-felix-adobe-cq5aem/ as I could find only this post online, but as I am a beginner I couldn't implement it. Need guidance in implementing such RESTful webservice in CQ5

Answer (score 5):

CQ5 is based on Apache Sling which is inherently RESTful, so you don't usually need additional libraries. In your case (and unless the users info is already available as Sling resources, I don't remember if that's the case) implementing a Sling ResourceProvider is enough to provide a browseable RESTful representation of those resources. See the [Sling docs](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html) for more info, they point to a simple [PlanetResourceProvider](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/resourceprovider/) as a minimal example.

Comment: This is an interesting concept.. i've always consumed web services in AEM but not exposed from AEM.

Comment: @Bertrand Delacretaz Thanks for replying. Actually the thing I need to achieve is that any call should just look and function like rest call i.e. the URL should support variables as well. e.g. http://10.143.1.90:4503/fetch/users/date/11-Sep-2015 so here date 11-sep-2015 is a parameter to the webservice which will filter users based on this date. Also to note is external application will be using this webservice which I was talking about.

Comment: You can implement URLs like /fetch/some/parameters with a ResourceProvider, just mount it on /fetch and map the resource path to the appropriate data.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz I will try your way too but I have a question like will this be like exact REST webservice ?As it will be used in some SAP tool which needs REST webservice and that generates WADL file from that REST URL automatically. Earlier the same functionality I tried to achieve through servlets by giving suffixes(parameters), thinking that the tool will not be able to differentiate if its a REST or servlet but surprisingly WADL generation failed in the tool which I believe was because that was servlet and not a REST webservice. Will be really thankful if you can suggest something .

Comment: WADL? hmmmm......if you have a single RESTful entry point, you can probably generate whatever definition is needed manually. And if it's a single entry point anyway, adding multiple additional libraries just for that sounds a bit like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the REST webservices working with AEM/CQ5. Even after installing the packages for JAXB for CQ5. It seems like sling overrides the resolving before it goes to the JAXB annotation handler. Due to lack to time had to implement an alternative approach where CQ5 will be timely writing the json data to an shared location as json file and the third party applications will fetch the files from there. 
This will however impact the performace as schedulers are to be written and also it's not a recommended approach but still it will work in my scenario.
Thanks all for helping me.